# Narrowing type conversion in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am learning Java and completely new to programming. I am trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes in this code:

```
short c = 234;
byte d = (byte) c;
System.out.println(d);
```

The output is -22. Can someone explain me what magic happening behind the scenes?

Comment: First to all, you must to understand the binary representation of integers, then, you have two primitive types, with different ranges (and number of bits), when you truncate the value 234 to be a byte, 234 became a negative number because the binary representation.

Comment: and type`short` is 16 bit,and `byte` is 8 bit.

Comment: Bytes are signed. 234=256-22. Throw away the 256, because none of it fits into a byte, and you have -22.

Answer (score 2):

The number `234` in binary is ‭`11101010‬`.

Although this number fits in 8 bits, a byte in java is signed, so the largest possible byte value in java is 127.  And when the most significant (leftmost) bit is set, this means "negative number", so the number you get is negative.

Now, you might wonder why the number you get is `-22` when `1101010` is not `22`.  The answer to this can be found by studying the two's complement representation of numbers.

Here is the wikipedia article for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 1):

A narrowing conversion tries to fit a value with a larger represented type in a narrower represented type.
If the value with a larger represented type doesn't overflow the narrower represented type, no problem, the value doesn't change.

For example with byte where the max value is 127, this code will value the byte variable with 127 as it stays in the bounds of the narrow type :

```
short c = 127;
byte d = (byte) c;
System.out.println(d);
```

Otherwise you have an overflow. It is your actual case.

For example try this code that overflows by 1 the byte type :

```
short c = 128;
byte d = (byte) c;
System.out.println(d);
```

The `byte` variable will be valued with the next value after `127`. 
But it doesn't exist. So the JVM loops on the `byte` range (`-128` to `127`). 
It uses so the minimal value for a `byte` :  `-128`.

With `short c = 129;`, it would produce `-127`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> *Can someone explain me what magic happening behind the scenes?*

no magic at all...  check what are the limits that [primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) can hold in java

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
>   It has a minimum value of **-128 and a maximum value of 127** (inclusive).
>   The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
>   where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
>   place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
>   that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
>   documentation.

so

```
short c = 234;
```

will not fit a byte, that is why you need to [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html), the negative resulting value is what you get after that cast operation

Comment: I understand that. But my questions actually is about information loss in narrowing conversion. What is the algorithm of casting in this situation? Why do we get -22 as output why not -30 or another value? In the beginning I thought that we should get 127 as it is the closest value to 234 which byte type can hold.

Comment: @AmacOS Because it throws away the high-order bits and interprets what's left as an 8-bit signed value.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer from @Mike Nakis. The value for bytes is -128 - 127. By explicitly telling the compiler to cast with `(byte)` you say to the compiler to not care about the range constraints and fit it no matter what.

If you did not use the cast the compiler will warn you by printing

`incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from short to byte`